# reCaptcha v3 with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate reCaptcha (v3) to a ColdFusion site. I'm not too hot on the CF syntax and currently I'm seemingly getting nothing back from the verify request on the server side.

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong and/or point me in the right direction please?

**Client Side:**

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6..."></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('6...', {action: 'contact'})
        .then(function(token) {
            $("#recaptchaToken").val(token);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've got a hidden field `recaptchaToken` in my form and I can see the `token` value going in to it.

**Server Side:**

```
<cfhttp
  url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
  method="POST"
  result="captchaResponse">
  <cfhttpparam
    type="formfield"
    name="secret"
    value='6...'
  />
  <cfhttpparam
    type="formfield"
    name="response"
    value='#form.recaptchaToken#'
  />
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var=#captchaResponse.filecontent# />
```

I'm getting a red box output titled `object of java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`

I've tried to dump both `captchaResponse` and `captchaResponse.filecontent` to no avail.

I'm expecting data in the form of:

```
{
  "success": true|false,      // whether this request was a valid reCAPTCHA token for your site
  "score": number             // the score for this request (0.0 - 1.0)
  "action": string            // the action name for this request (important to verify)
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

### Update

The solution seems to be as Alex suggested below:

```
<cfdump var=#toString(captchaResponse.filecontent)# />
```

This gives me a JSON string in the format expected so I can convert this to an object and complete the verification.

Comment: How about `toString(captchaResponse.filecontent)`?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion is the website running on?

Comment: I think it’s version 9

Comment: @Alex perfect - this gives me the content I expect! Thanks

Comment: Alex, you should post thst as an answer. @scgough - You should use that with an IsBinary check, in case the API changes in the future and starts returning a string.

Comment: When you do a `<cfdump var="#captchaResponse#">`, what's the `Content-Type` header value/`Mimetype` value? It *should* be `application/json` (or something to that effect) - is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever `cfhttp` is not sure how to treat a response, the raw content stays untouched and is kept as Byte array. This usually indicates that the Content-Type header is not specified by the responding server or the content was only partially retrieved.

To force a string representation of the content, you can use [`toString()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/tostring.html) to convert the raw Byte array, e.g. `toString(captchaResponse.filecontent)`. The function is quite robust and can also handle already converted strings, so it is usually safe to use.

However, there is something else to be aware of here. When using `cfhttp` without setting the `throwOnError` attribute to `true` (the default value is `false`), failed HTTP requests will still return a result, a crippled result. The struct will not contain the `fileContent` key and thus cause an exception at runtime. You might want to add error handling here, in case `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` is not reachable or the accepted TLS protocol is not supported by your JRE. We had this issue with SNI and TLS 1.2 with a former version of ColdFusion, namely 8. Be warned.

Comment: Cheers Alex! Noted!

Comment: @scgough The byte array can be any character encoding, but `ToString()` cannot magically guess the right one. If you don't specify one, it will use the default encoding set in your ColdFusion server. Depending on how the JSON is encoded and how your CF Server is set up, this may work. But may also fail, resulting either in silent data corruption or run-time errors. Always specify an encoding when converting bytes to string, never rely on a default. A sensible assumption for JSON payloads (and web data in general) is UTF-8: `toString(captchaResponse.filecontent, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: @Tomalak ok, great thank you I will take that in to account as well. My reCaptcha integration is now working thanks to all your help, everyone!
I don't code day-to-day in CF but it has me reminiscing to the old days of Classic ASP with some aspects of it!

Comment: That was the point behind my comment on your question. There's a chance that if you send an `Accept: application/json` request header (`<cfhttparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json">`), the server responds with a proper `Content-Type`, which would in turn remove the need to decode anything manually.  Worth a shot.