# How to implement recaptcha v3 in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, recaptcha-v3

Making first call to Google for getting the token from `contact_m.cfm` and submitting it to the same page for verifying it. Using ColdFusion call next to protect secret key. Calling the function remotely to invoke the ColdFusion function. Doing this as realized ColdFusion renders and do not look for changes.

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('token', {action: 'contact'}).then(function(token) {
    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "./contact_m.cfm", 
        type: "post", 
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify( {googleToken: token} ),
        success: function(result){
            $.get('./contact_m.cfm?func=googleVerification', function (r) {
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

Verifying the token with Google:

```
<cffunction access="public" name="googleVerification"> 
    <cfargument required="true" type="any" name="myArgument"> 
    <cfset requestBody = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />

    <cfif  isJSON( requestBody )>
        <cfset token = DeserializeJSON(#requestBody#)/>

        <cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" result="googleResult">
            <cfhttpparam name="secret" type="formField" value="6Lf9IrAUAAAAAOhEdBvk1ZyIKX6eUqS06GaSXG_F">
            <cfhttpparam name="response" type="formField" value="#token.googleToken#">
        </cfhttp>

        <cfset googleResponse = DeserializeJSON(#googleResult.FileContent#)/>
        <cfset isHuman = #googleResponse.success#/>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

And JavaScript function to check if Google success or fail:

```
<script>
        function validateHuman(){
        <cfoutput>
            var #toScript(isHuman, "isHuman")#;
        </cfoutput> 
        console.log(isHuman);

        if (isHuman == 'YES') {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
</script>
```

And allow user to submit the form if Google verifies:

```
<form id="form3" action="contact_m.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateHuman();">
```

I get error which says: `isHuman` is undefined.
Related Question: [reCaptcha v3 with ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431330/recaptcha-v3-with-coldfusion)

Comment: `isHuman` is only being set in your CF function, not where it is being called (javascript). You need to pass `isHuman` to your javascript some how.

Comment: @fyroc Can't I use `<cfoutput>var #toScript(isHuman, "isHuman")#; </cfoutput>` for accessing CF variables?

Comment: You can but the CF variable you are calling is in a function being called via JS (Client Side). You cannot define variables like that. You need to either move that logic to the CF code on that specific page or return that variable in the AJAX call then pass it thru via JS.

Comment: @fyroc do you mean passing value to it like `onsubmit="return validateHuman(#isHuman#);"` or is it different syntax?

Comment: Do you understand how client side vs server side work? With server side functions the process needs a page refresh to run. ` $.get('./contact_m.cfm?func=googleVerification', function (r) {});` is not doing what you think it is. You cannot run an entire serverside function using a client side method. I'll make an answer to be more clear

Comment: I don’t really have an answer because I’m noticing you’re doing a post to the entire CF component. I’m really not sure what you’re trying to achieve here. You need to add isHuman as a return in the CF function.. use Ajax to call that method to get that variable then use JavaScript to pass that variable to your JS function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe late here, but in case a workable solution was not found, the following may help (or for future readers).

Seems what was desired was code to use reCaptcha v3 with Coldfusion.  Here's a simple file (form.cfm) form that uses v3 to validate if a human is processing the form.  You can expand on it for your specific purpose.

These lines went in the Application.cfm or Application.cfc file

```
<cfset application.SiteKey = "_Your_Site_Key_from_Google_">
<cfset application.SecretKey = "_Your_Secret_Key_from_Google_">
```

These lines were saved in a file I called form.cfm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<cfoutput>#application.SiteKey#</cfoutput>"></script>
</head>
<body>

<cfif ISDEFINED('FORM.FirstName')> <!--- check if form was submitted and if so run code below --->

    <cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=#application.SecretKey#&response=#FORM['g-recaptcha-response']#" result="Response" />
    <cfset Return = deserializeJSON(Response.FileContent) />

    <cfif Return.success IS 'true' AND Return.score GT 0.5> <!--- check if true and if score is greater than 0.5. Run code below if all good. --->

        <cfoutput>Human: #FORM.FirstName# #FORM.LastName#</cfoutput>
        <!--- you can do database entry and/or email results here --->

    <cfelse>  <!--- if not a human, do this. I usually remove the else part completely, but if you need to do something with the robot, do it here.  --->

        Most likely a robot.

    </cfif>

<cfelse> <!--- show form --->

    <form method="post" action="/form.cfm">  <!--- submit form back to itself --->
      First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text"><br>
      Last Name: <input name="LastName" type="text"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit">
      <input name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" type="hidden" /> <!--- javascript below gives this a value from google. --->
    </form>

    <script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<cfoutput>#application.SiteKey#</cfoutput>', {action: 'homepage'})
            .then(function(token) {
                document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
            });
        });
    </script>

</cfif>

</body>
</html>
```

This is an adaptation of this tutorial from PHP to CF: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGNH_lbpmm8

If you get a lot of false positives when using this on your form, then increase the acceptable Score (0.6 or higher... 1.0 is max). Don't go too high, or you'll filter out legit submissions.  This # would replace the "0.5" in the cfif statement `Return.score GT 0.5`.

Hope this helps someone. Please correct me if that was not what you were looking for.

Comment: Hello Scott, I tried this code but it always things im a robot. Any idea?

Comment: One thing I changed was "cfset Return" to something other than Return.  Since ours is all in cfscript "return=" throws an error since it's reserved for functions.